# How to configure android studio using java to use .tflite file?

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, kotlin

I used [Teachable Machine](https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/) to train my machine learning model to recognize different sounds. However, after exporting the trained model file containing labels.txt and sounclassifier.tflite I was unable to incorporate it using java. All the examples are in Kotlin and I could not find any examples that involved Java. How can I configure tflite file to work with java for the android studio which is using java?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of official TensorFlow Lite examples written in Java:

- [Image Classification](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/image_classification/android)
- [Smart Reply](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/smart_reply/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/smartreply)

You can also find more community Java examples at the [awesome tflite community repo](https://github.com/margaretmz/awesome-tensorflow-lite).